# Why if I use a cycle for the input, the algorithm is slower

Tags: java, time-complexity

I want to calculate the execution time of analizeString() using System.currentTimeMillis().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String myString ="";
    for(int character = 0; character < 50000; character+=10000){
        for(int i = 0; i < character; i++){ 
             myString =+ randomCharacter();
        }           

        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        analizeString(myString);
        long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        printTimeInFile(time2 - time1);

    }}
```

in this case when the input is 40000, the time I find is around 4sec. But if I don't use cycle like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String myString ="";
    long input = 40000;
    //for(int character = 0; character < 50000; character+=10000){
        for(int i = 0; i < input; i++){ 
             myString =+ randomCharacter();
        }           

        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        analizeString(myString);
        long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        printTimeInFile(time2 - time1);

    }
```

time is around 0.3sec.

With the cycle the program is very slow.
Why is there this difference? My hypothesis is that the previous time is added too.
Any help? Thank you!

Comment: The second example has 40000 iterations, the first example has 10000 + 20000 + 30000 + 40000 iterations.

Comment: @Arnaud yes, but they don't add up 'cause every iteration I take again the time. Am I right?

Comment: you write in your code `myString =+ randomCharacter();` which mean the string is always the last char. I think you want `myString += randomCharacter();` notice the `+=`

Comment: myString =+ randomCharacter(); is just a mistyping, if it would be in code he would get a compilation error.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel yes, this is a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first Example you have 10000 + 20000 + 30000 + 40000 = 100000 iterations and your method runs last iteration for a string of 100000 chars.

- First iteration you have timing for 10 000 chars
- Second iteration you have timing for 30 000 (10 000 + 20 000) chars
- Third iteration you have timing for 60 000 (30 000 + 30 000) chars
- Fourth(last) iteration you have timing for 100 000 (60 000 + 40 000) chars

In second example you have a string of 40000 chars. This why the timing is different.

Check your analizeString() method, with increasing string by 2.5 times you get timing increase by more than 13 times (4 sec / 0,3 sec)

Comment: Oh my god, I forgot to reset the string at the end of the cycle. I just lost 2 hours for this stupid thing. I wanna cry ahah. Thank you.

Comment: @Simion even if you are correct, this is a very bad performance test, it should have been written with a library that can handle all of the things that we might not be aware of, like `jmh` for example

Comment: @Eugene I agree, but this is a completely different question